# HTML Table Display for browser detection

Tags: html

I just found a website http://www.browser-details.com/browser-detection/ which shows some of the details of the user's computer system.

As I am learning HTML tables display, I tried displaying the above site similarly through HTML. I am very sure this is not exact code to retrieve and display information like the above site, but I just want to confirm whether my way of writing HTML code is proper or not.

Here is my code sample to display details:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<table width="100%">

<tr>
<td>
<div style="background-color:red;">
<table align="center">
<th>Browser</th>
</table>
<div style="background-color:blue;">
<table align="center">
<td>
Slim Browser
</td>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</td>

<td>
<div style="background-color:red;">
<table align="center">
<th>Operating System</th>
</table>
<div style="background-color:blue;">
<table align="center">
<td>
Windows 7
</td>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</td>

<td>
<div style="background-color:red;">
<table align="center">
<th>IP Address</th>
</table>
<div style="background-color:blue;">
<table align="center">
<td>
117.85.48.222
</td>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>

<td>
<div style="background-color:red;">
<table align="center">
<th>JavaScript</th>
</table>
<div style="background-color:blue;">
<table align="center">
<td>
Enabled
</td>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</td>

<td>
<div style="background-color:red;">
<table align="center">
<th>Cookies</th>
</table>
<div style="background-color:blue;">
<table align="center">
<td>
Enabled
</td>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</td>

<td>
<div style="background-color:red;">
<table align="center">
<th>Color Depth</th>
</table>
<div style="background-color:blue;">
<table align="center">
<td>
24
</td>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</td>

</tr>

</table>
</html>
```

Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Up until recently I used tables rather than divs for my layout, mostly because I learned HTML in 1999 and then went into software engineering and didn't need to keep up with modern web design techniques, so as far as your right to use tables are concerned, go ahead! I learned how to use divs properly now and looking at that page and the fact you are already using divs in your code, you might really consider using divs, ESPECIALLY if you are just learning tables (learn it right the first time rather than wait like me) But if you still want to learn tables for your own reasons, let us know.

Comment: As for the table structure itself, there is no need to have tables within tables wrapped in divs, it looks like everything you are trying to do with the nested tables can be done in the TRs and TDs in combination with CSS aimed at the TD for background colors. And how "correct" do you want to be? is this just for HTML validation or do you want to use it for a portfolio?

Comment: I still want to learn tables

Comment: If it can be done in the TRs and TDs in combination with CSS aimed at the TD for background colors, please help me with the code. How to do it?

Comment: I want to use it for a portfolio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce your table to something like this

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        Operating System
    </th>
    <th>
        Operating System
    </th>
    <th>
        Operating System
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Windows 7
    </td>
    <td>
        Windows 7
    </td>
    <td>
        Windows 7
    </td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <th>
        Operating System
    </th>
    <th>
        Operating System
    </th>
    <th>
        Operating System
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Windows 7
    </td>
    <td>
        Windows 7
    </td>
    <td>
        Windows 7
    </td>
</tr>
```

Rather than retype all the text, I just duplicated the cells.

Your CSS might look something like this:

```
table{
    width:100%;
    border:3px;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:30px 0px;    
}
th{
    background-color:#888;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:1em;
    border-top: 1em solid #fff;
}

td{
    background-color:#eee;
    text-align:left;
    padding:1em 2em 1.5em 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check validity of your code with the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/).